# Building a FlexUnit runner (4.0.0.b2) with Ant fails with static methods?

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, flexunit

I have a project that is built using Ant. Before the actual project is built and committed, a test runner is executed to validate the consistency.

So far everything worked fine, but once I have added a test case for a class that was using a static method, the Ant build started quitting halfway with no meaningful message.

Is this a common-case for the FlexUnit runner, to have problem with static calls in the tested classes, or is it something very particular in my project?

Comment: Could you post some code, especially the lines that break the build? If you have a Flash Player debugger, looking at flashlog.txt can also be a good start because unless you are capturing debug statements in your IDE, this is where the output is available.

Comment: I would if I could, but it's very project-specific and I'm not allowed. The line that makes the build fail, however, follows this pattern: `SomeClassName.staticMethodCall();` - the moment it's commented out, everything works just fine.